# How to Get the Request from the Controller in Web API Inside the Windows Service.?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

I am using the Windows Service inside a MVC Application. In order to avoid the Pooling between the Windows Service and Database . I thought of using the MVC Web API. I Don't know , how to call Windows Service methods in MVC Controller with the help of Web API usage inside the Windows Service..
Please Help me....

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by `I am using the Windows Service inside a MVC Application`. How are you using it? Does your windows service expose any web service interfaces? Please elaborate.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.In our Project , We are using the MVC Application. and for the Back end Task to run , we are using the Windows Service.In order to run the  back end tasks we need to poll with Database, Get the task details and  run in windows Service., In order to avoid this poling  , I need an Web API Support to Get the Task details Parameters from the MVC Controller into the Web API Controller.   If any other way is there .... Please tell me.